the MEV (Maximal Extractable Value) Solana sandwich bot and how to input these results in file tree in cli with updated dependencies of 2024
the MEV (Maximal Extractable Value) Solana sandwish bot and how to input these results in file tree in cli with updated dependencies of 2024
Does any one know of a good open source project that works with MEV and can snipe coin. I was thinking of creating my own coin and managing the spread of my coin in this fashion like creating my own echo system of managing my price but I wanted to test this out in an ethical way. Can some one lead me to the promise of achieving this?
